# How can I check if a service exists from Python?

Tags: ros, python, service, rospy, ros-service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This question](http://answers.ros.org/question/211992/check-if-service-advertised-successfully/) has an answer for roscpp; what is the equivalent solution for Python?

EDIT: I do not want to wait for the service.  I want to take one action if the service exists and a different action if it doesn't exist.

A hack might be to wrap a wait_for_service call in a try/catch to catch a ROSException and verify that that ROSException was a timeout, but that's very ugly and I'm not sure what the minimum required timeout should be to ensure that extant topics do not cause the Exception.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263005/how-can-i-check-if-a-service-exists-from-python?/) by [BJP](https://answers.ros.org/users/30235/bjp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2017-06-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a function in the rospy API to get a list of services: http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/rospy/html/rospy.service.ServiceManager-class.html#get_services

I guess this would return a list of all registered services and you could check if the service you are waiting for is in this list.

Edit: I haven't tested the API call I linked in the original answer. I used  http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/rospy/html/rospy.service.ServiceManager-class.html#get_services

It works for me:

```
>>> import rosservice
>>> service_list = rosservice.get_service_list()
>>> print service_list
['/rosout/set_logger_level', '/rosout/get_loggers']
```

---

Originally posted by [Zubin Priyansh](https://answers.ros.org/users/24060/zubin-priyansh/) with karma: 161 on 2017-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-06-03**:
Have you tried this?

**Comment by [Zubin Priyansh](https://answers.ros.org/users/24060/zubin-priyansh/) on 2017-06-03**:
@NEngelhard I had successfully gotten a list of services in rospy, but now I realize it wasn't with this particular API call. I used this call: http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/rosservice/html/rosservice-pysrc.html#get_service_list . I should edit my answer accordingly.